# Intellij UI freezing due to "long scala calculation"

Tags: intellij-idea

Intellij is occasionally freezing on my fastest/newest Mac. I have not pinpointed the action occurring: but in general it is while editing `scala` code.  Seems that it could be normal editing of code or also showing popups of possible code choices for fill-in.

Here is a strong "hint" of what is happening from the intellij logs:

```
org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.util.UIFreezingGuard$$anon$1: 
Long scala calculation on UI thread canceled
```

I see that error message approximately at the times that the freezes occurred: three times in the past fifteen minutes for example.

Here is an illustration: at the moment shown in the screenshot I can do absolutely nothing with Intellij directly. By quickly switching focus to *ANY* other os/x app and then back to Intellij it gets unfrozen:

[image]

Here are IJ version details:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.2
Build #IU-163.10154.41, built on December 21, 2016
Licensed to ****
You have perpetual fallback license for this version
Subscription is active until February 9, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-408-b6 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
```

The `Activity Monitor` shows plenty of RAM available and the CPU is consistnely at single digit percentage utilization. As direct evidence the IJ GUI is snappy - until it freezes.

Are there any known workarounds for this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you believe your problem could be related to the icon rendering calculation for the Scala plugin as described here? 
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206002459-Is-there-a-way-to-disable-features-to-solve-performance-problems-

This says it can be worked around by disabling the toolbar that it's a current bug in the Scala plugin. Does this work at all?

Comment: No - i do not have any toolbars enabled.  Please remove this answer - it should have been a comment on the question .

Comment: Okay, under Languages and Frameworks -> Scala, what do you have checked under the performance tab and the editor tab?

Comment: All default values

Comment: Well at this point I would suggest going here https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241235-Reporting-performance-problems and taking a more detailed profiling of your issue and posting it here or if you think it's bad enough, reporting a problem to JetBrain's bug tracker.

Comment: Thanks for looking: but you may have noticed that your input is commentary - not an answer.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, the only reason I have not removed it was because of what we've discussed here. I don't know if we can move this up to your parent post and I can remove this answer, but hopefully this might help someone else along the way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132657/discussion-between-javadba-and-stephen-carman).